# PHP File Upload on IIS Server

Tags: php, iis

I'm trying to create an upload script on a Win 2012 Server running IIS 8 and PHP 5.6. We can't get the PHP error logs running which is a big downer because it's hampering our ability to troubleshoot, so I figured I ask if anyone that has experience with PHP on a Windows server that might be able to help out.

I'm no fan of running PHP on IIS, but I have no choice in this case so please no flames there. We developed on a LAMP stack because we didn't have a WIMP stack available, when we tried to migrate we had much success but the upload script failed so I'm going to post the pertinent parts here and if anyone can lend a hand that would be awesome.

If I'm an idiot, moron, etc. I apologize.

```js
  // File Variables
 $_FILES["image"]["name"] = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").
 '.png';
 $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

  //Path Variables
 $target_dir = "../uploads/";
 $target_path = $target_dir.$_FILES["image"]["name"];


  // Upload
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
   $actual_link = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].
   "/uploads/".$filename;
   $myMessage. = '<br/><img src="'.$actual_link.
   '" width="300" height="224" /><br/>';
 }
```

I appreciate any assistance or guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all make sure that in `php.ini` `safe_mode = Off` and set `display_errors` or add following lines at the start of your code

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
?>
```

I had same problem with `Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5 with PHP Version 5.6`

I tried everything that I could find on Internet but I was helpless. I was trying to assing permission of user `"IIS_IUSRS"` to "C:\Wdinwos\Temp" folder which is configured in php.ini as `upload_tmp_dir` and the folder where I was uploading the files/images. It was useless

Then I find out in my IIS `Authentication -> Anonymous Authentication` There is `"IUSR"`. Then I added this user to "C:\Windows\Temp" and the folder where I was uploading files/images and it worked.